# Gaps and Islands - How to Sum Each Group of Consecutive Rows by ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

Below is my current SQL code and output. I only need to get the sum of EFF_DAYS for consecutive (or single) rows where CD is equal to STG (highlighted in yellow).

```
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TMSP, EFF_DT) RN, 
Z2.* 
FROM (
    SELECT CASE WHEN (LAG_CD IS NULL OR LAG_CD NOT IN ('STG')) AND CD IN ('STG') 
    THEN RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TMSP, EFF_DT)

    WHEN CD = LAG_CD AND CD IN ('STG') 
    THEN RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TMSP, EFF_DT)

    WHEN CD = LAG_CD AND CD != LEAD_CD 
    THEN RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TMSP, EFF_DT)

    END AS CASES, 
    Z.* FROM (
                SELECT ID,
                LAG(CD) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TMSP, EFF_DT) AS LAG_CD,
                LEAD(CD) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TMSP, EFF_DT) AS LEAD_CD,
                CD, 
                TMSP, 
                EFF_DT, 
                END_EFF_DT,
                DATEDIFF(day, EFF_DT, END_EFF_DT) AS EFF_DAYS
        FROM #POSTCHG_ROWS 
        WHERE ID IN ('ABC123', 'XYZ789')
        ) Z
    ) Z2 ORDER BY TMSP, EFF_DT
```

I've tried all kinds of row number and rank stuff, but I can't seem to get the CASES column correct. I've spent hours looking at other gap-island sql solutions, but haven't come across the exact scenario below.
[image: Current SQL Query Output for 2 IDs]

Ideally my CASES column would be output like below so I can GROUP BY CASES, ID, the starting TMSP of the consecutive row block and then calculate: SUM(EFF_DAYS).
[image]

Below is my goal output:

[image]

Comment: Post the data in a consumable format, not images. Preferably DDL and DML statements, as we can just copy and paste and run the code then, but otherwise well presented tabular formatted `text`.

Comment: How do you present it as formatted text?? In a code block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only interested with series of adjacent "CTG" rows. I think that the simplest approach is a window count of non-"STG" values to define the groups, then filtering and aggregation:

```
select 
    id,
    min(tmsp) tmsp,
    min(eff_dt) eff_dt,
    sum(datediff(day, eff_dt, end_eff_dt)) sum_eff_days
from (
    select
        p.*
        sum(case when cd = 'STG' then 0 else 1 end) 
            over(partition by id order by tmsp) grp
    from #postchg_rows p
) p
where cd = 'STG'
group by id, grp
```

Comment: Missing a comma after select p.*, but otherwise this worked out for me.